# Auto-rotate scanned image with python

Tags: python, scikit-image

We have a large number of images that have been scanned from grid-based paper with graphs drawn on them. The graphs are not straight, but the grids are consistently spaced and cover 80% of the page.

Most of them are "nearly straight", but we would like to rotate them so that the grid is perfectly straight. In some cases, they may need to be rotated up to 20 degrees, but most often it is less than 10 degrees.

Actually doing the rotate is somewhat straightforward using PIL or skimage, but the challenge is automatically detecting how many degrees to rotate the image by.

How would we identify the rotate angle required?